# Табы bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как растянуть вкладки переключения на всю ширину экрана, и чтобы при изменении разрешения они также меняли значение по высоте и ширине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на всю ширину табы можно сделать так: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified

Comment: точно) спасибо!

Comment: @AndreyShamray если Вам подошел ответ, отметьте его решением(галка под цифрой слева от ответа).